# Reactjs can't pass map.item property to another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to learn how to pass the state of a class component to another class component. However I'm getting an error below when accessing the key `'id'` in item `todo`.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

    {this.props.todoLists.map(todo => (
        <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} toggleComplete={this.props.toggleComplete.bind(this)}/>
    ))}
```

But when I log `todo.id` in console, it's getting printed.

```
    {this.props.todoLists.map(todo => (
        console.log(todo.id)         
    ))}
```

Why it doesn't work when passing it through another component, I know it's possible but why it's throwing an error?

Comment: The code seems correct, can you create demo of the issue.

Comment: Also show how `this.props.todoLists` looks like, at least one element from the array. Thanks!

Comment: I think the error comes from your `TodoItem` component, it's your `todo` object that is undefined, could you please post both of your components. You can also create a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do not use console.log inside return in render method as it does not work properly.
Please try with this code.

```
{this.props.todoLists && this.props.todoLists.map(todo => (
        <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} toggleComplete={this.props.toggleComplete.bind(this)}/>
    ))}
```